# Can I set IP header from node.js

Tags: node.js, tcp, ip

There is a need to set DSCP values in packet headers in messages sent from node.js WebSocket. From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services) page, I understood I have to modify DS field in the IP header to set custom DSCP value. Is it possible to set it from node application and for some specific messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Node.js does not expose any IP level API (current version: [v11.10.1](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/)). So you cannot set custom IP header only with JavaScript code.

However, in the Node.js application, you can write [C/C++ addon](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/addons.html) to send the custom IP packet and integrate that addon in Node.js code.

Take module [raw-socket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket) for example, it writes raw network logic in C++ and expose that in JavaScript interface.